# Which Babel transformers should I blacklist for a Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing ES6+ code and compiling it with Babel (currently using `{stage: 0}` as my `.babelrc` config).

So I'm compiling everything right down to ES5. But I'm exlusively targeting Chrome v47+, which supports some ES6+ features natively.

Which of the default [Babel transformers](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/) can I blacklist (disable) and still have my code run in Chrome 47+?

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ will give you a list of supported and not supported features. You could compare this to the babel transformers list

Answer (score 3):

### Available ES6+ Functionality

[Take a look at this page](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#es6) to see what features are fully implemented and enabled by default in Chrome and [this page](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/) for the Babel transformers to which they correspond.

```
ES6 Feature             Release   Babel Transformer                   Spec. Compliant*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rest Parameters        | 47      | es6.parameters                    | ✔
Spread                 | 46      | es6.spread                        | ✔
Arrow Functions        | 45      | es6.arrowFunctions                | ✔
Extended Obj. Literals | 45      | es6.properties.shorthand/computed | ✘
Computed Prop. Names   | 44      | es6.properties.shorthand/computed | ✘
Classes                | 42      | es6.classes                       | ✘
Template Strings       | 41      | es6.templateLiterals              | ✘
Generators             | 39      | regenerator                       | ✘
JS iterators           | 38      | es6.forOf                         | ✘
Block bindings         | 18      | es6.blockScoping/constants        | ✘
```

*I have derived the column Spec. Compliant (re: Chrome not Babel) by looking at what draft of the specification the current implementation is based. For example 'Editor's Draft' -- I assume this means a potentially incomplete or incorrect implementation.

______

### Babel Transformer Dependencies

These are the dependencies that transformers have on each other that I have identified from the Babel source code:

```
Transformer               Dependencies
--------------------------------------------
es7.classProperties      | es6.classes
es7.decorators           | es6.classes
es7.asyncFunctions       | es6.classes
es7.objectRestSpread     | es6.destructuring
```

______

### Conclusion

It seems that no ES6 Babel transformer is dependent on another. So, any ES6 feature that is implemented in Chrome, **and is spec. compliant**, you no longer need to rely on Babel for. And these are: [`es6.parameters`](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread), [`es6.spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread), and [`es6.arrowFunctions`](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows).

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the references too :)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks. But you're ruling out using a Chrome native feature if it's not 100% spec compliant? From looking into exactly what is not covered in the [compat table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#chrome47), it looks like there are several extra features I could enable if I was willing to accept small non-compliant details – eg. ES6 classes only work in strict mode, which is no problem if you always use strict mode anyway. Is that a fair position or am I missing something?

Comment: @callum - There is a risk that the implementation changes and your code no longer functions as expected. Of course your position is fair so long as you are willing to forgo stability in this regard. I admit the chances of an implementation changing enough to drastically affect your application is small, my answer was catering to those features we can absolutely say are safe enough to start using natively. You have some breathing room!

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not quite as simple as disabling transformers for features the environment supports, because some transformers have dependencies on others. For example, the `es7.asyncFunctions` transformer depends on `es6.classes`, even for environments where classes are natively supported. By "depends", I don't mean that  `es7.asyncFunctions` automatically invokes `es6.classes`, I mean that `es6.classes` has to be individually enabled (either explicitly or by not being blacklisted). See [babel/babel#2415](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2415).

Possibly also of interest: [babel/babel#2340](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2340).

Comment: This. Plus there are many features Chrome *supports* in v47, but are either not 100% complete or not spec-compliant. Depending on the OPs code requirements and application needs, they may want to disable transformers appropriately.